# Remove string spaces in C - why the words after the white space are also removed?

Tags: c, string, loops, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying a beginner problem in C on Codewars: I should write a function that removes spaces from a given string, then return a new (dynamically allocated) string.

Example : the input string `HELLO WORLD` in `str_in` requires the output `HELLOWORLD`, but what my code returns in `noSpace_str` is `HELLO`.
`WORLD` is nowhere to be found, and I'm trying to understand why.

(thank you in advance for any answer)

My code :

```
char *no_space(const char *str_in)
{
    int len = strlen(str_in);
    char *noSpace_str = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char)); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str_in[i] != ' ')
            noSpace_str[i] = str_in[i];
    }
  
    return noSpace_str;
}
```

Comment: Where are you _shortening_ `noSpace_str`?  (Conversely , does it have enough memory if there are no spaces?)

Answer (score 2):

When your code encounters a space, it does not copy anything at all. This leaves a gap in the buffer that contains whatever was there before, in this case, a null byte (0x00). Null bytes are used to terminate strings, therefore the string ends right after the word "HELLO". Without immediately giving out the answer, you need to begin copying *after* the space, rather than ignoring it.

Comment: indeed, as the buffer allocated comes from malloc() you are not warranted to get a null character, so it should be considered undefined behaviour, as the allocated buffer has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

There are major problems in the code:

- the size allocated for the new string is too small: there is no space for the null terminator. You should allocate at least `len + 1` bytes.
- you only copy the characters that are different from space (`' '`), and leave the other entries in the allocated string uninitialized.  The sixth byte in the allocated block is probably a null byte, which would explain why you get `HELLO` as the output, but anything else could happen.
- also note that `len` and `i` should have type `size_t` for consistency with the return type of `strlen`.

To achieve the goal, you should use a different index for the source and destination arrays and ensure a null terminator is appended.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *no_space(const char *str_in)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str_in);
    char *noSpace_str = malloc(len + 1);
  
    if (noSpace_str) {
        size_t j = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (str_in[i] != ' ')
                noSpace_str[j++] = str_in[i];
        }
        noSpace_str[j] = '\0';
    }
    return noSpace_str;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this VG answer was recently edited by a low-rep user, adding only unnecessary _casting_ (that should be explicitly discouraged.)

Comment: @Emre -- you can edit typos in the code of others, but don't make changes to the code itself. In this case it is idiomatic to _not_ cast the result of `malloc` in C (C++ is different) and your change was just pointless noise. This is not entirely your fault: your edit was approved by some poor editors. I have voted to reject a similar but more drastic edit you proposed to another answer on this page, and rolled this edit back. I hope that chqrlie does not mind my rolling this back....

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other good answers, if you want to only allocate the needed size and not extra, make 2 passes, counting what you need on the first pass.

This 1st loop replaces `strlen()`, which itself is a walk down the string.  Makes sense, as long as code is walking the string, to count non-spaces.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* no_space(const char *str_in) {
  size_t size_needed = 1; // For the null character.
  for (const char *s = str_in; *s; s++) {
    if (*s != ' ') {
      size_needed++;
    }
  }

  char *noSpace_str = malloc(size_needed); // Cast not needed
  if (noSpace_str) { // If allocation succeeded ...
    char *destination = noSpace_str;
    for (const char *s = str_in; *s; s++) {
      if (*s != ' ') {
        *destination++ = *s;
      }
    }
    *destination = '\0';
  }
  return noSpace_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one variable per array to iterate through them. That of the destination must only be incremented if there is a character copy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *no_space(const char *str_in)
{
    int len = strlen(str_in);
    char *noSpace_str = malloc(len+1);

    int j=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if(str_in[i] != ' ')
      {
          noSpace_str[j] = str_in[i];
          j++;
      }
    }
    noSpace_str[j] = 0;

    return noSpace_str;
}

int main()
{
    char tab[] = "   123456    7890  -   12345  67890   ";
    puts(no_space(tab));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no error checking, wrong types for indexes and `len`

Comment: @gulpr, I disagree, indexes can be of any numeric type that makes them to be compatible with the array index (even floating point could be used ---just look at the temperature example of K&R that mixes integers with floating point in a for loop) (remember automatic conversion) He could have even written `for (int i = 0.0;...` and no problem on that (the `double` literal is converted to an int at compilation time and no warning is issued.

Comment: @LuisColorado it does not matter if you agree or disagree. int is not correct for sizes. I will not even comment on the rest ......

Comment: @gulpr, Those are not sizes.... are numeric integral types.  If you use an `int`, it will be implicitly converted to the proper type (e.g. `size_t`).  This is a C feature, and I didn't invent it.  You can even use floating point to index an array.  In C this is correct.  That you don't agree is what is incorrect.

Comment: @LuisColorado and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Other (current) answers have pointed out that the code needs two distinct index counters; one for the source array and one for the destination array.

Other answers have stated the allocated buffer needs to accommodate a terminating NUL (not counted by `strlen()` of the source string.)

Other answers have demonstrated that the returned pointer from `malloc()` can be NULL. Do not use NULL pointers. Always test return codes from system functions (like `malloc()` or `fopen()` and curtail processing if needed.

Here's a compact alternative. "*Less (working!) code is better code*"

```
char *no_space( const char *str_in ) {
    if( !str_in ) // can happen!
        return NULL;

    char *str_out = malloc( strlen( str_in ) + 1 ); // casting can lead to bugs

    if( str_out )
        for( char *p = str_out; ( *p = *str_in++ ) != '\0'; ) // copy everything
            p += *p != ' '; // retain non-SP characters

    return str_out;
}
```

A more capable version would take a second `char` parameter allowing this function to filter out all occurrences of any character the caller wants (not just SP).

An even more capable version would take a second `char*` parameter allowing this function to filter out all occurrences of any characters the caller wants excluded (conveyed to the function with `char *excl` as a parameter.)

The simple test

`cp += *cp != ch;`

could become

`cp += !strchr( excl, *cp );`

The last possibility is left for OP to explore and understand.

Comment: @LuisColorado "_...lateral effect ... pointer arithmetic ... can result in U.B._" Oh, really! Please explain how! I'm more than willing to learn!

Comment: @LuisColorado For all of its "airs", DV'ing this answer only confirms that SO is nothing more than "_social media_" (with all that the appellation connotes.) Thanks for today's grin. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */

char *no_space(const char *str_in)
{
    int len = strlen(str_in);

    /* don't cast the return value of malloc()  Only do it if you are
     * considering using the code in C++ programs, which is, by the
     * way, discouraged (use new/delete for this in C++).   
     * Doing that will make the compiler check that you have
     * actually #include <stdlib.h> which will pass unseen (putting the
     * cast informs the compiler you are doing the right thing and will
     * silent the lack of the proper prototype.  If you use
     * the cast, and the error that it produces is still provoking a cism
     * between C entusiasts. */
    char *noSpace_str = malloc(len + 1); /* sizeof (char) is always 1 */
```

`strlen()` returns the length of the string, but this length doesn't include the space for the final `'\0'`, required for `strlen()` to properly find the end of the string and count the number of characters until to.  You need to allocate one more byte for the null at the end, so use `len = strlen(str_in) + 1;` instead.  This is indeed an error, if the input string has no spaces at all, as in that case, it will overrun the buffer allocated, making you to put the `'\0'` one space beyond the end of the allocated buffer, which is wrong.

If you plan to copy to a newly allocated string, then  you have to just copy the chars, but skip the blanks.  This means you will have to use two indices, not only one, because the difference between them will state for the number of characters skipped, so you can do better doing this:

```
    int src_index = 0, dst_index = 0;
    while (src_index < len) {
        if (str_in[src_index] != ' ')
            noSpace_str[dst_index++] = str_in[src_index];
        src_index++;
    }
    noSpace_str[dst_index] = '\0'; /* put a '\0' at the end to properly terminate the string */
```

(observe that, if the source string at source index shows a space, no space is copied, and `dst_index` is not incremented also)

or, if you prefer to use pointers:

```
    char *str_out = malloc(strlen(str_in) + 1),
         *src, *dst;
    for (src = str_in, dst = str_out; *src; src++)
         if (*src != ' ')
             *dst++ = *src; /* copy the chars pointed by src and dst */
    *dst = '\0';  /* properly terminate the string */

    return str_out;
```

Comment: `noSpace_str[dst_index] = '\0';` ... `dst_index` is out of scope by this time... Won't compile. Same for the ptr version with `char *dst`...